# Why is object becomes null? (Rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Im a newby, so maybe its a very silly qustion ) 
I have a controller:

```
 class MainPageController < ApplicationController

  def uid=(xid)
   @uid=xid
  end  

  def idx
  response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
  @uid=params[:user_id]
  log=Logger.new(STDOUT)
  log.debug("UID #{@uid}")
  log.debug("#{params[:access_token]}")
  app=VK::Application.new(app_id: 4914826, app_secret: 'ZjeOFuApRPVdvL234Tsu', version: '5.31', access_token: params[:access_token])

  end

  def queue_req

  end

  def app_init
   #vkjson=app.friends.getOnline uid
   response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
   log=Logger.new(STDOUT)
   log.debug("UID FO JSON #{@uid}")
   render json: {'uid'=>@uid}.to_json

  end
end
```

idx - called by the default route. The default view - after initializing some js - calls init using ajax. And i get an answer, that @uid is null. In logs - in idx - @uid - is coorect, and in init - already is null. Why?

Here's the part of code of the page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
VK.init(function() {

 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/init', // JSON_URL is a global variable
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr_data) {
      alert ('Error')

    },
    success: function(xhr_data) {
      alert(xhr_data.uid)
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });

});
</script>
```

What is wrong in the code?
Thank you!

Comment: you're not sending data in your Ajax request and do you expect data in params variable?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do. But the answer is probably because each request is handled by a different instance of the controller's class. Thus instance variables aren't shared between requests.

Comment: @jphager2  I think u've understood what i need correctly. OK, I'll ask in other way ) When a user attends my page first time - i get (iav get :)) set of params, next time - i should already use this params. How can i save them (of course pesonal for every user), without sessions?

Comment: Well, if you dont want to use sessions or cookies, you should save the data to a database.  Though, if you aren't going to use cookies, then you will have to think about how you will identify users (like ip or passing url parameters around). Why cant you use sessions?

Comment: @jphager2, I don't need sessions, cause its an app for social network with thier own seesion mechanism. I chose the other method - I gather this params on the client side and keep them in assosiated array in JS, and just send this params to my server every time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Web requests, web servers, the web in general, is stateless. So when you set `@uid = params[:user_id]` in your `idx` method, it's valid for the life of that request/response, but the next request is handled by a new instance of your controller, and in that new instance `@uid` hasn't been set.

The way we fake state in the web world is using cookies, a cookie is sent back to the browser on their first visit, and the browser automatically sends that cookie back to the web server with each request. We can put any information we want into that cookie in the first request and the browser will send that back to us with subsequent requests - so we're able to fake statefulness.

Rails adds another security layer on top of cookies called sessions, which allows us to securely store information in the cookie, and then securely retrieve it in subsequent requests.

So, change your `@uid=params[:user_id]` to `session[:uid] = @uid = params[:user_id]` in your `idx` method, and then in `app_init` make the first line: `@uid = session[:uid]`